# Big Query Date function

Tags: mysql, google-bigquery

I have a dataset where I have first order date mentioned in column, and I want to find difference between the current date and first order date. I want the date_diff function or any other way. I want the same for google bigquery.

Comment: I'm not clear what your problem is - you are aware of the datediff function so presumably are also aware of NOW() and CURDATE() Both can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71479114/big-query-date-function. If you have a specific problem please publish sample data, expected output and your code together with an explanation your issue.https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: its like i have a column of first_payment_date where dates are mentioned as 2022-03-09 so i want to find users in between current date and the first payment date so that i can sort users in the dataset more than 7 days from their first payment date. in mysql i used datediff(durrent_date(), first_payment_date) as paid_days, the same i want for bigquery where the format states error if i follow the same as mysql.

Comment: thats what i need to check for last 30 days users dataset. i need days difference in days count

Comment: In bigquery DATE_DIFF(date_expression_a, date_expression_b, date_part) , https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions - slightly different to mysql

Comment: yah i know this but the same format its not working in bigquery.

Comment: So your question really is can I develop in mysql and port to bigquery without code changes? I doubt it but this isn't the forum for that sort of question and I don't know so I'm dropping out..

Comment: ok no worries, thanks but thats not what u got.